# How add a link to an icon of another component not in app.js in React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working on a react project
In the App.js
I have all my imports and routers
Now I want to apply a router to an icon on the nav that routes to settings.
And I did that by creating another component for *Settings*, then I import the *Settings* to my App.js then link it to my *icon*  route

So when I click it, it displays Settings.

Now the issue is

On that my settings page
I have lots of contents and icons

Now I want that if I click a
( *General* *Settings* *icon* ) it should display General Settings.

*So how will I now add route to that icon.*

My General Settings(page) is a different component. And not in the App.js page

Comment: You could create nested routes under `Settings` route. And specify a outlet for it on `Settings` page.

Comment: So what you can do is add another route like this <Route path="/settings/general" element={<GeneralSettings />} />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use nested routes, Robin Wieruch has a good post about it: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-router-nested-routes/

/index.js

```
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
      <Route path="settings" element={<Settings />}>
        <Route path="general-settings" element={<GeneralSettings />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

/App.js

```
...
<Link to="settings">Settings icon</Link>
```

/Settings.js

```
...
<Link to="general-settings">General settings icon</Link>
<Outlet />
```

Comment: thanks.. but this is throwing an error:Link and Outlet is not defined  in the /Settings file

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as the same  way as if it was in the app.js

App.js (react 18)

```
<Route path="/url/to/settings" element={<SettingsComponent/>} />
```

The Component where you 'have lots of contents and icons'

```
<Link to={/url/to/settings}>
   <Icon />
</Link>
```

Comment: When I did did this on first try it throws an error:  Link is not defined in that component

Comment: thanks.. but this is throwing an error:Link and Outlet is not defined  in the component where I have lots of contents